# WPF binding combobox to nested enum in different namespace works not in Designer

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, enums, combobox

I have the following definition in my xaml file to bind a combobox to a nested enum:

```
<Window xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:Company.Project1.Component1.SubComp1;assembly=Project1.Component1">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="testEnum"
                        MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="myns:Class+NestedEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

This works fine, however I get the error message "The type 'Class+NestedEnum' was not found" and the Designer won't load the file.

How do I have to do the binding of the enum to the comb obox, so that the Designer works as well? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I'm using VS2008

Comment: Resolved it by putting the enums in a separate Enums.cs file and not nested inside a class. I still would like to know, why moy other way didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem.
This is a known bug : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vswpfdesigner/thread/ea668b28-636b-4f99-b1e7-49dc4d98b263
I hope this will be fix in the next Visual Studio (2012).
I think you used the best solution : removing the enum from the class.